# Android - LiveData vs WeakReferences

Tags: android, android-livedata, weak-references

I'm using the suggested architecture with ViewModel and LiveData. I need to retrieve some data from an API, so I do that through repositories, and then ViewModel exposes LiveData to the UI.

The problem is that calls to the API may fail, and the UI needs to react on that cases.

I've already solve this, by using a Wrapper class that holds my data and also a status that can be an error status (And some more extra information).
This works, but I would prefer that the ViewModel manage my own Listener so that I have methods like onSuccess() and onError(). The issue with this is that I lost the Lifecyle control of LiveData.

I've recently learnt about WeakReference, and it seems that LiveData replaces the use of WeakReferences, but I wonder why is this ? What's the benefit I get from using LiveData instead of my own Listeners with WeakReferences ?

Comment: Here's an idea; You can via Retrofit, if you're using retrofit2 for api calls, setup a failure or success response and return some boolean from your Repository class back to your View Model. Your Activity/Fragment can then check this variable and display the UI accordingly.

Comment: why reinvent the wheel. if you want to write your own listeners for every single thing (database calls, api calls, UI updates etc) you could do that OR you can just use the architecture component provided by google...

Comment: @a_local_nobody Yes, you are right, but I'm asking if in case for some reason I decide to create my own listeners with WeakReference, I will lost some very beneficial feature provided by LiveData. Maybe there are cases with WeakReferences in which I'll have memory leaks much more frequently than with LiveData

Comment: Can u post your wrapper class that you used for transferring data and status?

Comment: There are not that much significant technical differences between just plain call backs vs `LiveData` or `RxJava`. The main difference is in the design. If you use `LiveData` or `RxJava`, you can completely isolate your ViewModel layer from the View layer, while if you just use call backs your View somehow needs to pass listeners or even its own reference to the ViewModel, and the ViewModel needs to retain these reference.

Comment: Also more on technical side, `WeakReference` only resolves memory leak problem, while `LiveData` can do little more. For example, it is very possible that in somce case view gets destroyed before the `Activity` instance is removed. Therefore if you use `WeakReference` you still need to check if `Activity` is finished, while using `LiveData` you don't really need to care because it is lifecycle-aware.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is based on observer pattern and thus keep your UI always synced with the latest data.
2. It's life cycle aware component and thus only updates UI when it's  in active state.
3. Memory leak safety as Hi gets destroyed ,old references also gets cleared.

Comment: Ok, but I can implement my own observer pattern with more callback methods, and if I use WeakReferences old references also get cleared when the GarbageCollector decide to destroy them.
Maybe I'm not understanding correctly what you said

Answer (score 0):

The livedata is designed to not lose the state, which is stored in the view model when changing configurations and unsubscribe when lifeCycleOwner reach destroyed state.

However, if your application is killed by the system, then you should take care of how to save the view state of the model using a bundle or https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel-savedstate

If you need a one-time event, then use https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java